# Scala Lift - Dynamic page chrome

Tags: scala, lift

I have a page which is passed an id from which the content is determined. What I'm looking to do is dynamically replace the pages "chrome" depending on the content.

So if I have a db record "Book", I'd like to display the Book chrome in templates-hidden.

Thanks for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a snippet that selects the template you want and pass the xhtml NodeSeq containing the template selection to it:

```
<lift:TemplateSnippet.dynamicTemplatePicking>
    <lift:surround dynamic:template="" at="content">
        <h2>some heading</h2>
        <p>some text</p>
    </lift:surround>
</lift:TemplateSnippet.dynamicTemplatePicking>
```

And the snippet code:

```
class TemplateSnippet {  
    def dynamicTemplatePicking(xhtml :NodeSeq) :NodeSeq = {
        bind("dynamic", xhtml, AttrBindParam("template", Text("default"), "with"))
    }
}
```

By changing the `"default"` in `Text("default")` inside the snippet you can choose another template depending on your needs. Maybee you want to do something like `def choose (record: Record) = record match { case b: Book => "booktemplate"}` and so on...

Source: [Mads Hartmann's posting](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Choose-template-in-a-custom-Loc-td1962806.html)